# su produces "registered driver" messages

Tags: kernel, fingerprint-reader

I tried to install my fingerprint reader and now each time I run `sudo -i` I see this list of messages:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: fp:debug [fp_init] 
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver upekts
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes3500
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes4000
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes2501
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes2550
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver uru4000
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver vcom5s
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver upeksonly
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes1610
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes1660
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver aes2660
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver vfs101
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver vfs301
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver vfs5011
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver upektc
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver upektc_img
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver etes603
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver vfs0050
fp:debug [register_driver] registered driver elan
fp:debug [fp_exit]
```

I don't know how I caused this exactly. I think I compiled this: https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90 and installed some of these packages:

`libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui`

I was not able to get the fingerprint sensor working. How do I now get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
cd Validity90/libfprint
sudo make uninstall
```